# Error on this program.The error is on line:1,2,3.

Tags: java

```
/*OridinalForm.java
 * ----------------
 * This program displays the the number with their suffix.
 */
import acm.program.*;
public class OridinalForm extends ConsoleProgram {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void run(){
        while(true){
         int no=readInt("Please enter the numberand press 0 to stop:");
         if(no==0){
             break;
         }
             println(oridinalForm(no));
         }
     }
         private String oridinalForm(int nos){
         String result="";
         switch(nos){
         case '1':result=nos+"1st";
         case '2':result=nos+"2nd";
         case '3':result=nos+"3rd";
         default:
    1        if(nos.charAt(nos.length()-1)=1){
                 result=nos+"1st";
             }
    2        if(nos.charAt(nos.length()-1)=2){
                 result=nos+"2nd";
             }
    3        if(nos.charAt(nos.length()-1)=3){
                 result=nos+"3rd";
             }
             else result=nos+"th";
         }
         return result;
     }
  }
```

the code is to explain the result for the no with different conditions. The error is on line:1,2,3. PLease explain me the debugging method. Im little unknown about that method.

Comment: `nos` is an `int`. It doesn't have a `charAt` or `length` method. As a matter of fact, it can't have any method.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace? We need to know the *type* of error.

Comment: also compare using == not =

Comment: @Kevin Can you please add that as an answer?

Comment: `(char)1` is the character that has ASCII code 1. `'1'` is the ASCII character `1`, which has code 49. So you either write `nos.charAt(whatever)=='1'` or `nos.charAt(whatever)==49`.

Answer (score 4):

Here, `nos` is an `int`.  But in your `switch` statement, you are comparing it to `chars`: `'1'` can be converted to an `int` implicitly for comparison, but that is the ASCII value of `0x31`, or `49`.  Use the actual numbers in your `switch` statement.

You cannot call a method on a primitive `int` type.  To get a specific digit, you can convert it to a `String` with `String.valueOf`, *then* call `charAt` on it.

Next, in this line (and the others like it),

```
if(nos.charAt(nos.length()-1)=1){
```

The `=` operator is the assignment operator in java.  Use `==` instead to compare `int` values.  Here's a tutorial about [Java operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
 private String oridinalForm(int nos){
     //                      ^^^ 
        if(nos.charAt(nos.length()-1)=1){
     //       ^          ^           ^
             result=nos+"1st";
         }
        if(nos.charAt(nos.length()-1)=2){
             result=nos+"2nd";
         }
        if(nos.charAt(nos.length()-1)=3){
             result=nos+"3rd";
         }
         else result=nos+"th";
     }
     return result;
 }
```

`nos` is an `int`. It doesn't have a `charAt` or `length` method. As a matter of fact, as it's a primitive, it can't have any method.

Also, as mentioned in other answers,  `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison (which is what you want).

Answer (score 0):

`nos` is an int, which is a primitive, and would not have any methods attached to it. I think your `if` statements should be `if(result.charAt(result.length()-1) == 1)`, and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at each of your if-statements, you will see that you are actually assigning a value to the character at the end of the string. `if(nos.charAt(nos.length()-1)=1){` should probably be
`if(nos.charAt(nos.length()-1)==1){`

Comment: A pedantic note: While `=` is an _assignment operator_, the line you mention does not _assign_ anything actually, and it would not even if the code compiled, since methods copy the return value (thus the client has no access to the field the value was taken from)